# Appending query parameters to specific URI

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to append the query string `?sort_by=id&dir=ASC&lim=2&flt=1` to any traffic going to `/admin/users.php`, which should result in:

```
/admin/users.php?sort_by=id&dir=ASC&lim=2&flt=1
```

I was attempting to follow this question/answer:

https://serverfault.com/questions/311487/nginx-rewrite-append-a-parameter-at-the-end-of-an-url

By doing the following:

```
location /admin/users.php {
  rewrite  ^(.*) $1?sort_by=id&dir=ASC&lim=2&flt=1 break;
}
```

Also tried:

```
  location /admin/users.php {
    rewrite  ^ /admin/users.php?sort_by=id&dir=ASC&lim=2&flt=1 last;
  }
```

But any traffic going to `/admin/users.php` comes back without the query string added. I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Any suggestions for implementing this correctly?

---

The `default.conf` in its entirety:

```
server {
  listen 4000;
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html/src;

  include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

  index app.php index.php index.html index.htm;

  client_max_body_size 500m;


  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    rewrite  ^/admin/?(.*) /$1 break;
    rewrite ^/admin/users.php$ /admin/users.php?sort_by=id&dir=ASC&lim=2&flt=1 break;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to rewrite an URI of the PHP file, most likely you have a PHP handler looking somewhat like

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

The `~` modifier specifies a regex matching location, and locations of that type have a greater priority than the prefix ones (only exact match locations with the `=` modifier have greater priority than the regex ones). Moreover, you should not try to do it with the additional location block - all that you can achieve with that approach is the endless loop. Try this instead:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    rewrite ^/admin/users.php$ /admin/users.php?sort_by=id&dir=ASC&lim=2&flt=1 break;
    include fastcgi_params;
    ...
}
```

**Update**

You have two `rewrite` directives in your PHP handler location. The first one will truncate the `/admin` prefix from any URI that start with that prefix. The second one will add additional query arguments to `/admin/users.php` URI, but it will be already rewritten to the `/users.php`. Moreover both `rewrite` directives have a `break` flag which means that if the first rule will be executed, the second one will never be reached. To combine both rules, try the following preserving the `rewrite` directives order:

```
rewrite ^/admin/users.php$ /users.php?sort_by=id&dir=ASC&lim=2&flt=1 break;
rewrite ^/admin/?(.*) /$1 break;
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave it and several variations a shot but still run into the same issue. Probably something I'm still doing wrong. I've updated my original question with the `default.conf` in its entirety.

Comment: See the answer update.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, thanks!